# how can i do dot production in python?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

Write the function dot_product(M, N), that takes as parameters two matrices M and N, and returns a new matrix containing dot product of these matrices.

I understand the logic but not sure how to do the multiply each rows and columns this is what i have so far

```
def dot_product(M, N):

    """ takes as parameters two matrices M and N, and returns a new matrix
        containing dot product of these matrices
    """

    assert( len(M[0]) == len(N)), " innter length differnet " 

    new_matrix = zeros(len(M[0]) , len(N))

    transP = transpose(N)

    storing_values = []

    for r in range(len(M)):

        for c in range(len(M[0])):

            storing_values += M[r][c] * transP[r][c]
```

I'm using helper function transpose to rotate the matrix N so when i iterate I'm looking at same columns and rows for both matrices.

output should look like this :
 [[26.00, 4.00]
 [62.00, 13.00]]

Answer (score 1):

Using the numpy in-built dot product function looks easy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Should be something to the effect of:

```
import numpy as np

def dot_product(M, N):
    return np.dot(np.asarray(M), np.asarray(N))
```

In general, a lot of functionality in python has already been implemented in packages like numpy, I try not to reinvent the wheel. Not sure if this is acceptable in your case as this seems to be a homework problem, but this is the easiest way to get the dot product of two matrices.

Comment: By the way, I got to this answer by doing a simple google search: "dot product in python"

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I'm not allowed to use numpy